# Cannot update the user profile. (Laravel 8 & Vue.js 2)

Tags: vue.js, jwt, vuex, laravel-8

I am naive of Laravel and Vue.js. I'm using JWT authentication for my backend and VueX for the frontend.
I want the user able to change their picture, name and email but I got an error when I try to save. and for your information, I try to edit and save name and email first, update the picture will do after this.

**My Profile page**
[image]
**and this is the error that I received.**
[image]
**here is my code:**

```
<template>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:25px">
    <div class="main-font">My Profile</div>
    <div class="d-flex row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
                <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(updateProfile)">
                    <div class="d-flex py-4">
                        <!-- <img class="profile" src="/img/profile.jpg" alt="" > -->
                        <div>
                            <template v-if="!currentUser.profile_image_url" >
                                <img class="profile" src="/img/default.png" alt="">
                            </template>
                            <template v-else>
                                <div class="profile">{{currentUser.profile_image_url}}</div>
                            </template>
                        </div>
                        <div class="my-auto ml-5">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn upload text"><i class="fas fa-upload fa-sm pr-2"></i>Upload new picture</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-10 p-0 m-0">
                        <ValidationProvider name="Name" rules="required|alpha" v-slot="{ errors }">
                            <label  class="text">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control form-text" placeholder="Enter your username" v-model="userForm.name">
                            <span class="error-messsage">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                        </ValidationProvider>
                        <!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-10 p-0 m-0 mt-4">
                        <ValidationProvider name="E-mail" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ errors }">
                            <label class="text">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email"  class="form-control form-text" placeholder="Enter email" v-model="userForm.email">
                            <span class="error-messsage">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                        </ValidationProvider>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn col-10 p-o save-but">SAVE CHANGES</button>
                </form>
            </ValidationObserver>
        </div>
        <div class="w-50">
            <img class="bg-img" src="/img/profile-bg.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script:**

```
<script>
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver, extend } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full';

export default {

    components: {
        ValidationProvider,
        ValidationObserver,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            userForm: {
                name: '',
                email: '',  
            },
            
            error: null,
        }
    },
    watch: {

    created () {
        this.userForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.currentUser));
    

    },

    computed: {          
        currentUser(){
            return this.$store.getters.currentUser;
        },
    },

   
    methods: {
        //  updateProfile (){
        //     this.$store.dispatch('updateUser'); 
        //     var _this = this;
        //         // ajax call to POST this.profile then
        //     _this.$store.commit('update', 
        //         {
        //             // name: 'currentUser',
        //             data: this.userForm
        //         })
        // },

        getUser (){
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            axios.get('/api/auth/userprofile',{
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.userForm= response.data.user;
                // this.userForm.email = response.data.user.email;

            })
        },

        updateProfile () {
        axios.put('/update-profile',
            {
                name: this.userForm.name,    
                email: this.userForm.email,
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.userForm.name = response.data.name;
                this.userForm.email = response.data.email; 
                swal({
                    icon: "success",
                    text: "Update Succesfully!",
                });   
            })
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

**controller:**

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth as FacadesJWTAuth;
use App\Http\Requests\Users\UpdateProfileRequest;

class AuthController extends Controller

{
    public $token = true;
  
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
    
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
 
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
                    [ 
                      'name' => 'required',
                      'email' => 'required|email',
                      'password' => 'required',  
                 
                     ]);  
 
         if ($validator->fails()) {  
               return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);  
            }   
 
 
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();
      
        if ($this->token) {
            return $this->login($request);
        }
  
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $user
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
  
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
    
        $input = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $jwt_token = null;
  
        if (!$jwt_token = JWTAuth::attempt($input)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
  
        // return response()->json([
        //     'success' => true,
        //     'token' => $jwt_token,
        // ]);

        return $this->respondWithToken($jwt_token);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required'
        ]);
  
        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate($request->token);
  
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User logged out successfully'
            ]);
        } catch (JWTException $exception) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Sorry, the user cannot be logged out'
            ], Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    //update user profile
    // public function updateProfile(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
    // {
    //     $user = Auth::user();
    //     $jwt_token = auth('api')->tokenById($user->id);

    //     $input = $request->all();

        
    //     if ($jwt_token) {
    //         // $user = Auth::user();
    //         // $users = $user->user;
    //         $user->name = $request->input('name', '');
    //         $user->email = $request->input('email', '');
    //         $user->save();
    //     }
    //     // $user->update($request->all());
     
    //     // return ['message' => 'Updated the user info'];
    //     return $this->respondWithToken($jwt_token);
        
    // }

    public function updateProfile(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
    {
        DB::transaction(function() use ($request){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->name = $request->input('name','');
            $user->email = $request->input('email','');
            $user->save();
        });

        // $user->update([
        //     'name' => $request->name,
        //     'email' => $request->email,
        // ]);
        return ['message' => 'Updated the user info sucessfully!'];
    }

    public function userProfile()
    {
        // return response()->json(auth()->user());
        $user = auth('api')->user();
        $token = auth('api')->tokenById($user->id);

        return response([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ]);

        // return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
  
    public function getUser(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required'
        ]);
  
        $user = JWTAuth::authenticate($request->token);
  
        return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
    }

      
    //   Refresh a token.
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(JWTAuth::refresh());
    }

  
    // Get the token array structure
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'user' => $this->guard()->user(),
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => JWTAuth::factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    public function guard() {
        return Auth::Guard('api');
    }

}
```

**routes:**

```
Route::put('/update-profile',  [AuthController::class, 'updateProfile']);
```

**store.js**

```
import {getLoggedinUser} from './auth';
const user = getLoggedinUser();

export default {
    state: {
        currentUser: user,
        isLoggedin: !!user,
        loading: false,
        auth_error: null,
        reg_error:null,
        registeredUser: null,
        update: null,
    },
    getters: {
        isLoading(state){
        return state.loading;
        },
        isLoggedin(state){
            return state.isLoggedin;
        },
        currentUser(state){
            return state.currentUser;
        },
        authError(state){
            return state.auth_error;    
        },
        regError(state){
            return state.reg_error;
        },
        registeredUser(state){
            return state.registeredUser;
        },
        update(state){
            return state.update;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        login(state){
            state.loading = true;
            state.auth_error = null;
        },
        loginSuccess(state, payload){
            state.auth_error = null;
            state.isLoggedin = true;
            state.loading = false;
            state.currentUser = Object.assign({}, payload.user , {token: payload.access_token});
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.currentUser));
        },
        loginFailed(state, payload){
            state.loading = false;
            state.auth_error = payload.error;
        },
        logout(state){
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            state.isLoggedin = false;
            state.currentUser = null;
        },
        registerSuccess(state, payload){
            state.reg_error = null;
            state.registeredUser = payload.user;
        },
        registerFailed(state, payload){
            state.reg_error = payload.error;
        },
        // update(state, payload) {
        //     state.currentUser = payload.data;      
        // }
    },
    actions: {
        login(context){
            context.commit("login");
        },
        // updateUser(context) {
        //     const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        //     axios.put('/api/auth/update-profile', {
        //         headers: 
        //         {
        //           Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        //         }
        //     })
        //     .then((response) => {
        //         context.commit('update', response.data);
        //     })
        // }
    }
};
```

**auth.js**

```
import { setAuthorization } from "./general";

export function registerUser(credentials){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      axios.post('/api/auth/register', credentials)
      .then(response => {
          res(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          rej('An error occured.. try again later.')
      })
  })
}

export function login(credentials){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      axios.post('/api/auth/login', credentials)
      .then(response => {
            // setAuthorization(response.data.access_token);
            res(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          rej('Wrong Email/Password combination.')
      })
  })
}


export function getLoggedinUser(){
  const userStr = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if(!userStr){
      return null
  }

  return JSON.parse(userStr);
}
```

The login and register function are working well just the profile cannot be updated. Please help me if you have any solution or ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For update profile method, Bearer token need to pass to axios request as well.

```js
updateProfile () {
    const token = this.$store.getters.currentUser.token // get the token from state
    axios.put('/update-profile',
            {
                name: this.userForm.name,    
                email: this.userForm.email,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" // add content-type
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.userForm.name = response.data.name;
                this.userForm.email = response.data.email; 
                swal({
                    icon: "success",
                    text: "Update Succesfully!",
                });   
            })
}
```

---

P.S. If you want axios to include Bearer token in all requests at all time without specify it on each request, you can `axios.defaults.headers` but it is another topic

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the solution but still got the same error. Is it because my backend doesn't receive the token?

Comment: still have unauthorized error? Did you try the api on Postman or any other place to see if it is working?

Comment: I think the JWT part should be no problem as you can get user profile from `/api/auth/userprofile` part. The auth guard should be working.

Comment: I check with the postman, the API can update my profile, but when I go to the frontend still the same issues and this is the code in the controller. I found that the function seems like didn't use the token and I using DB: transaction. Do you think is that a problem?

Comment: public function updateProfile(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
    {
        DB::transaction(function() use ($request){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->name = $request->input('name','');
            $user->email = $request->input('email','');
            $user->save();
        });
        return ['message' => 'Updated the user info sucessfully!'];
    }

Comment: If postman is ok, the backend should be correct and we can focus on frontend.

Comment: I updated the answer to get the token from state . can you try it out? It should be able to get the correct token to do the put request `const token = this.currentUser().token`

Comment: I refer to `getUser()` to answer your question previously . However,`localStorage.getItem('token')` is not going to give you the token because you are storing it with key `user` instead of `token`. If the `const token = this.currentUser().token` work, please change the way of retrieving token in `getUser()` as well

Comment: I used to change const token = this.$store.getters.currentUser.token, cause currentUser() shows me an error of not a function. But it still has the put 401 (Unauthorized) error. That's weird.

Comment: can you console log this.$store.getters.currentUser.token in updateUser, is there anything print out?

Comment: if no, I suggest you to use the localStorage directly. `const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))` and use `user.token`.

Comment: If localStorage does not help, please check the localStorage in browser, e.g. Chrome -> right click page -> Inspect -> Application -> Local Storage and see if the user is set and token is presented in the value. if yes, please attach the result here, may be the format is wrong.

Comment: Yes. There's a token printout. I have posted the screenshot with the token.

Comment: can you use that token to test your api in Postman?

Comment: Oh, I try just now and got this "message": "Unauthenticated."

Comment: the token should be expired if you just try it after 17:54

Comment: For how vuex works in your case, should be update user -> server return you the updated user -> commit the updated user to mutate(update) user state in store. so after you get the user, you should do commit `this.$store.commit('update', <updatedUserObj>` -> uncomment the update code in mutation to allow update state in store.

Comment: May I know what is the use for <updatedUserObj>?

Comment: <updatedUserObj> is  {name: 'xxxx', email: 'xxx' }, `this.$store.commit('update', {name: 'xxxx', email: 'xxx' })`, pass the updated user object to store.

Comment: If I open another question for this, could you please have a look?

Comment: yes sure. I think the community will help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

[the result of the console.log(this.$store.getters.currentUser.token)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgcAJ.png)

I can get the token

[and this is the localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBuu7.png)

even here I also get the token in the error

[PUT error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbPmM.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4pC0.png)

And here is the postman authorization that I put
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI07a.png)

**[the body part in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v02i.png)**

Comment: Can you try setting content-type as well, see below code above. It should be able to solve your problem.  `"Content-Type": "application/json"` with bearer token

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean change in postman?

Comment: { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,  "Content-Type": "application/json" } }

Comment: I saw it and tried. It still doesn't work.

Comment: or the headers should put before the name & email?

Comment: strange. can you confirm it is a json request? u can capture the body part in the Postman for me to check.

Comment: the axios params are url, data and options (which include the headers) and i see the headers can be attached in the request in the picture you provided. should not relate to the position of the params

Comment: I see, thanks for the explaination. Yes, I post it now.

Comment: i see it and it is a json request. very strange. maybe the website is still using the old token. have you tried logout and login again to test the put request on the website?

Comment: Wait, it's work!! It shows me updated successfully. Just after updated. It doesn't show the latest name that has been updated.

Comment: cool.  then there is only state problem left.

Comment: I think you somehow need to dispatch a call to vuex store to update the state?

Comment: You are a genius! You save my day><. Thanks so much^^!!

Comment: Please accept my answer and upvote it if you find it useful. Thanks. anyway, are you HongKonger?

Comment: May I know how its work, I'm not very familiar with Vuex .

Comment: Haha, I come from Malaysia.

Comment: haha. nice. your name seems like from HK.

Comment: Must vote, I will vote for you when I enough reputation^^!

Comment: Thanks! and hope you can solve it and you can still leave the comment here if you cannot find the way out.